# resetting scope data in ng-repeat error

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble resetting a scope model. I am sure I am making an obvious mistake that isn't so obvious to me.

```html
<div class="" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
 <div class="feed-entry">
  <div class="user-image-round" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ comment.comment_user_image }})'}"></div>
   <div class="right-text-section">
    <div class="commentor-name">{{comment.comment_user}}</div>
    <p class="comment-text">{{ comment.comment_text }}</p>
    
       
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="" ng-repeat="entry in comment.comment_response_entries">
   <div class="comment-entry">
    <div class="commenter-image-round" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ entry.user_image }})'}">
    </div>
    <div class="right-text-section">
      <div class="commentor-name">{{entry.user_name}}</div>
      <p class="comment-text">{{ entry.response_entry }}</p>
        
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="comment-post">
  <form ng-submit="addComment($index, sub_comment)">
   <textarea class="text-area" placeholder="Write a comment" ng-model="sub_comment" required></textarea>
   <button class="post-button">Post</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('App')
 .controller('CampaignCtrl', function ($scope){


$scope.addComment = function(index, subcomment){   
  $scope.comments[index].comment_response_entries.push({
    user_name : 'Daniel Tawfik',
    user_image : '/images/crowdcitizen/daniel-tawfik.jpg',
    response_date : 'October 1xt, 2015',
    response_entry : subcomment,
    response_entry_likes : 0,
    response_entry_liked : false,
  });
  $scope.sub_comment = '';

}

}
```

I have an ng-repeat on comments. On each comment entry the user should be able to post a response to the comment. ng-sumbmit calls addComment which takes the comment index pushes a comment_reponse_entry object the array. This works fine.

The problem I am having is that when I reset scope model with $scope.sub_comment = '' the textarea value doesn't update. It seems like the scope has changed, but I can't seem to access it again.

Comment: classic problem of not using object in `ng-model`. Primitive bindings get broken due to child scopes like `ng-repeat` .... rule of thumb is *"always have a dot in ng-model"*

Comment: @charlietfl because it was nested in the ng-repeat when I used the dot model, it would update the other sub_comment all of the textarea inputs. when i would enter text in it would update the model of all the comment scopes.

Comment: can be array or other scope object also using your `$index` of `comment`

Comment: @charlietfl to resolve it would I try to reset the scope model by setting $scope.$id.sub_comment = '';